# Progress bar and No internet connection in webview Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I am trying to get a progress bar which shows until the web page is loaded. and if user has no internet connection than a text or toast is showed... but i am unable to get it worked.. searched the whole website. i think its easy to add progress bar  to class that expends Activity...
here is my class and layout

```
package com.nirav.rpta.fragments;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.nirav.rpta.R;
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = heroespage.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    heroespage.loadUrl("http://google.co.in/");

    return rootView;
}}
```

and my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.nirav.rpta.fragments.OneFragment">
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
/></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a ProgressBar to your layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.nirav.rpta.fragments.OneFragment">
   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progress"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:indeterminate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in the code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

heroespage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                heroespage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Show error toast
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                // Show error toast
            }
        });

heroespage.loadUrl("http://google.co.in/");
```

Comment: that worked thanks..... progress bar is visible now... but there is no error message when there is no internet connection.. solve this also please

Comment: did you add code where I wrote:  "// Show error toast" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for the thing you want.

**Your layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.nirav.rpta.fragments.OneFragment">

       <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

       <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Your Java file should be like below:**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Resources
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

    WebSettings settings = heroespage.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    heroespage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
            if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(WebViewScreen.this, "You are offline.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    heroespage.loadUrl(URL);

    return rootView;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You must update your layout
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nirav.rpta.fragments.OneFragment">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>


And then find id of progressbar ProgressBar prog = view.findViewById(R.id.progbar);

to check internet connection use this method

public boolean isConnectingToInternet( Context _context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }

add this code in your oncreateview

heroespage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewCLient(){
  public void onPageLoadFinished(){
    progbar.setvisibility(View.Gone);
});
if(isconnectingInternet(getActivity()){

   heroespage.loadUrl("http://google.co.in/");
}else{
// show your toast here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide / show progress bar  you can use setWebViewClient which provide onPage strated and onPageFinished method

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Show Progress bar
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            // hide Progress bar
        }
    });
```

To check no internet connection , you can use below code

```
public static boolean isNetConnected() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Use above method before loading url

```
if(isNetConnected()) {
    heroespage.loadUrl("http://google.co.in/");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity() ,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```